# Symfony 2 and relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine

When I try to save `User` entity with `Related Profile` entity (I use `cascade={"persist"}` option) I have saved both entities, but `Profile` entity saving with empty `user_id` field.

- How I can solve this?
  Relations:

User:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Profile", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 */
```

Profile:

```
 /**
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="profile", cascade={"persist"})
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
```

Comment: Could you show your classes? (or relation config)

Comment: i added relations declaration. help i am newbie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cascade={"persist"}` is irrelevant here.

The way you defined this, you haven't created one (bidrectional) relationship where a User points to a Profile and the same Profile points back to the same User.

Instead you have two (unidrectional) relationships: The User points to a Profile and the Profile points to a (potentially) different User.

This is visible if you look at the tables. Your User table will have profile_id field and the Profile table will have a user_id field (but you only need either, bot both). And since you probably just set the Profile property in the User Entity, but not the User property of the Profile entity, the user_id field for the Profile table is empty.

You want a (single) bidirectional One-To-One relationship as described here:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional

The entity where you actually want to store the relationship in needs to have a `inversedBy` annotation parameter:

```
/**
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="profile", cascade={"persist"})
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
```

Comment: hm...i am read the doc. tried to do like yoy say but i have the same result... where is my problem?

Comment: if I remove, cascade option i get the error: A new entity was found through the relationship 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User#profile' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Profile@0000000044b8975e00007f2596c25aab. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"})...etc.

Comment: I didn't say to remove `cascade={"persist"}`, it's just not relevant to your problem. Did you update the schema of your tables? What do they look like. Is there only one of the fields (used_id in Profile, or profile_id in User), as a said it should be?

Comment: in profile table exist user_id field, profile_id in User is absent. when i change my relation like one-to-one-bidirectional doc say i update my schema...